# Creating and using a table in the same transaction

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run a certain module in ms access. This is the part where I start running into problems:

```
For i= asc("A") To asc("C") 
    DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
    '...a lot more code...
    strSql = "SELECT table.string, Count(*) INTO tableCount FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.string= table2.string WHERE table2.string Is Null AND (((table.string) Like [param])) GROUP BY table.string HAVING (((Count(*))>1))"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSql)
        qdf.Parameters("param").Value = Chr(i) & "*"
        Call qdf.Execute(dbFailOnError)
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        If DCount("*", "tableCount") = 0 Then 'check if there were records
            GoTo nextIteration
        End If
        '...a lot more code using tableCount if DCount shows that there are records...
    DBEngine.Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
Next i
```

When arriving at the `DCount` check I get an error :

**The Microsoft Access engine cannot find the input table or query 'tableCount'...**

And the table doesn't appear in the db. I tried running the query that is in `strSql` in the Create Query in Access. When asked for `param` I enter `A*` and it works fine. The table tableCount is not created in the database before the transaction commit, But I need it inside the transaction, and not only for DCount. Is there a way to use the table or it's data before committing?
Please ask for any additional information you need in order to answer me, in comments. I will respond right away.

Comment: I think the Execute method runs asynchronously and your code should be waiting for it to finish rather than continuing on. I looked up CreateQueryDef.Execute and these is an dbRunAsync option but it doesn't say what the default is if you don't use the option. My suggestion would be to modify the call to DCount to include your parameter, as a filter) rather than creating a new query each time. That way you won't be repeatedly updating tableCount and needing to lock it.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson Do you mean that the table is not created until the transaction is completed?

Comment: I think the table is locked because its being updated by your query. If you only update it once, with all your counts and without the HAVING clause, you can read from it with the DCOUNT function without having to repeatedly lock it.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson I don't understand what eliminating the HAVING will do. Can you explain more? Also, I edited the question after solving the second error. Please see if your answer still applies.

Comment: Can you call `CommitTrans` before `DCount`?  I don't know whether that change would break the rest of your code.  But if you can, does that error then go away?

Comment: @HansUp I did what you suggested and the error goes away. But I really need the rest of the code to be in the transaction. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I don't believe the new version of `tableCount` is available before `CommitTrans` so I don't see an alternate solution for you.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you for trying. You seem to be right. I will have to give up the transaction until someone else (hopefully) comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following it is simpler and keeps everything within the transaction:

```
Dim dbS As DAO.Database
Dim wsP As DAO.Workspace
Dim lngRecs as Long
Set wsP = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set dbS = CurrentDb
strSql = "SELECT table.string, Count(*) INTO tableCount FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.string= table2.string WHERE table2.string Is Null AND (((table.string) Like '" & Chr(i) & "*'")) GROUP BY table.string HAVING (((Count(*))>1))"
wsP.BeginTrans
dbS.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
lngRecs = dbS.RecordsAffected 
If Not lngRecs > 0 Then
   GoTo nextIteration 
End If
'Do whatever you like with lngRecs
wsP.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
```

Comment: DCount is not the only time I use the tableCount.  For example, later in the transaction I create and run a query that selects from a table using a join with tableCount. So you see, I need the **records** in tableCount before commiting the transaction. Will this answer help me with that?

Comment: RecordsAffected will give you the number of records. So instead of just checking if it is > 0, populate a variable with it and do whatever you like. What's the issue?

Comment: I don't get it. How does knowing the number of records allow me to do a join on them? All I will know is that there **was** a difference (which does help with the dCount,). I need to access the **data** itself in the records in order to do a join.

Comment: I think you are leaving something out. There is nothing to stop you from using a join. In your post, you create a querydef and apply parmeters to it, execute it, then count the records in the new table using dcount. You can accomplish the same thing by using your same SQL string, but including the 'parameter' in the where clause. dbS.recordsaffected tells you how many records are inserted into your new table. That is exactly what you are expecting dcount to give you. What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer is a good one for the DCount. But as you can see from my third comment in my code,`'...a lot more code using tableCount `, I need the **records** in the table for more code inside the same transaction.  I understand that `lngRecs` shows me **how many** records are in the table, and not **what** those records are. Am I wrong? Example: in the code after DCount I need to know "the first record is 'apple', 20. The second record is 'orange', 15." **Not** "there are 2 records in the table." If I am misunderstanding your answer, can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: 'a lot more code...' is not code. You should be able to access the records in the new table. Post some code (not a general statement) that does not work using my example.